# How to get total number of records across all databases in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way through which i can get total number of records across all the databases in **MongoDB** server.

There is command for finding total records in a particular collection of a databases. But i want to get the count of total number of records across all databases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use [`db.stats`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/)

```
db.stats().objects
```

The [`objects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbStats.objects) property return the count of documents in the database across all collections.

---

To get the total number across all databases, you may need to do something like this:

```
let client = db.getMongo();
client.getDBNames().filter( name => name !== 'local')
    .map( elt => client.getDB(elt).stats().objects )
    .reduce( ( acc, cur ) => acc + cur, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

can use this

```
var alldbs = db.getMongo().getDBNames();
for(var j = 0; j < alldbs.length; j++)
{
    var db = db.getSiblingDB(alldbs[j]);
    var collections = db.getCollectionNames();
    for(var i = 0; i < collections.length; i++){
      var name = collections[i];
      if(name.substr(0, 6) != 'system'){
          var c = db.getCollection(name).count() ;
          print(db + '  ' + name + '    ' + c );
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this simple python script

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
cot = 0
db_list = client.database_names()
for item in db_list:
    db = client[item]
    col = db.collection_names()
    try:
        num = db[col[0]].count()
    except Exception:
        num = 0
    cot += int(num)

print('\t' + str(cot))
```